# Code Prettify - Line numbers?

Tags: discussion, formatting, design

SE sites use Google Code Prettify for code formatting. While [it's still up in the air](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242889/code-block-prettify-for-code-review-after-graduation) as to whether we would be able to get SE to use community-voted code formatting, I've been experimenting with Prettify.

There are a few options for line numbering in Prettify, and I was interested to know what everyone thought would be best to use, if we were to have our own formatting.

I will post 3 answers with the different options. Please up- or down-vote according to your preference.

*PS: Please don't mind the colors right now, haven't got that far yet.*

<sub>*PPS: I took the code from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77401/linq-me-a-fizzbuzz) in case you are curious.*</sub>

Comment: Does copy & paste still work with line numbers?

Comment: AFAIK it does, at least on my machine (OS X). You're welcome to test it on your own: https://github.com/Cardshifter/cardshifter.github.io/blob/develop/prettify-test/prettify-test.html

Comment: You're right, [it works fine for me too](http://jsfiddle.net/z2yhcjp4/).

Answer (score 25):

### All lines numbers

*To clarify, as the question surfaced a few times, line numbers* ***do not*** *affect copy & paste, in other words, line numbers are not stored in the clipboard when you select the code.*

### DRAWBACKS

After some experimentation, it appears the line numbers do carry over using IE 11, but not on other browsers tested. This would make the copied code not compile until they are removed. This may be a pretty big deal breaker, as SE supports IE 11. (thanks @MarcAndre for pointing out)

Also, it would be nice if answers could retain correct line numbers when posting snippets; however there is no way to make a code block *not* start with line 1. Code in the question occasionally changes (i.e. it might get formatted a bit better) - answers referencing specific line numbers would potentially become confusing.

[image]

Comment: Having line numbers is a plus (IMO) since it makes it easier to refer to the code you have in mind. Especially in code review we deal with big chunks of code as it's good to submit a working code.

Comment: How does having line numbers impact the copy/paste process?

Comment: It has no impact on my machine, as in, line numbers are left out of the clipboard. I'm on Mac though, you're welcome to try it from your end: https://github.com/Cardshifter/cardshifter.github.io/blob/develop/prettify-test/prettify-test.html

Comment: @rolfl I got independent confirmation it works fine, see [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4962/code-prettify-line-numbers?noredirect=1#comment9345_4962)

Comment: The IE 11 is a pretty big deal breaker IMHO , since SE support that browser. I don't think using the edit option would be view as a valid alternative.

Comment: Can we change the starting number?  While we prefer complete code, it's not actually a requirement.  Also, it would be nice if answers could retain correct line numbers when posting snippets.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it always starts at 1 for each code block. The other thing about snippets, that I'm not sure.

Comment: Hm, I don't know - code in the question occasionally changes (i.e. it might get formatted a bit better) - answers referencing specific line numbers would potentially become confusing. I think quoting a snippet is more robust.

Comment: The more I think about it, and as much as I think line numbers would be/look nice... There are a few obvious drawbacks that may be more trouble than it's worth... Perhaps we should leave well enough alone?

Comment: @ChrisWue that's an invalid edit :( reformatting code violates the guidelines... but yes I also think quoting a snippet is more robust. It's also more obvious and doesn't require checking back against the answer

Comment: Not a fan of the dark colors.  It's really hard on the eyes.

Comment: Yeah I'll make a separate post once I start tinkering with colors and such.

Comment: It should be possible to make the line numbers not copy on IE11. Separate the line numbers from the code (tables?) or replace the line numbers with a .png. This one implementation not working on IE should not ruin the improvement.

Comment: @nwp You're welcome to fork it from my repo if you have any idea how to make it work. [This is where I keep the working code](https://github.com/Cardshifter/cardshifter.github.io/tree/develop/prettify-test).

Comment: I think line numbers are a bad idea. (i) They will tempt people to refer to code by line number instead of quoting the relevant portion, but that will be disastrous for readability of answers, because you'll have to keep referring back and forth. (ii) They waste horizontal space which is very limited on mobile devices. (iii) They don't even help when there's more than one code block.

Answer (score 9):

### No line numbers

*This is the setting that is currently in use on CR.*

[image]

Answer (score -22):

### Numbers every 5 lines

*Note that the different colored lines are also optional, that can be changed easily.*

[image]

Comment: This one feels a tad silly. If you're going to dedicate the space to line numbers anyway, might as well number them all! If the justification is "less clutter," I find that having odd line numbers draws my attention to them more than just numbering everything because it's unexpected.

Comment: I certainly don't disagree!