# New Site Design!

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/new-design-branding-for-code-review).

We have also themed the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackcodereview) and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the [privilege levels](/privileges) to higher thresholds.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug".

As we mentioned earlier, you will soon be able to select your own community ads. We're very close to the new year and the new ad cycle, and we have some exciting changes planned for these as well. These, too, will begin in December or early January so that you may enjoy the new changes.

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) theme!

Comment: May I be the first to congratulate our new robot overlords on the site update. To be honest I was confused at first (were the heck am I). But it looks good.

Comment: Thank you for the good work on the design, it's really awesome !

Comment: This is so beautiful.

Comment: Uh, oh, looks like I've lost my editing privilege! ;)

Comment: It is different, therefore I don't like it! Oh well, it'll be ok in a few days.

Comment: Congratulation! I was wondering what was that new icon in the "Hot Network Questions"

Comment: Amazing! Good work SE team!

Comment: Looks like the new design brought more activity

Answer (score 31):

Excellent design, hands down.  I admit I was a bit nervous as it was hard visualizing something that captured the essence of this site, but I think you've done it beautifully.

Definitely worth the wait, thank you.