# Why are the Code Review badge icons different from other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, badges

Can anyone tell me why the badge icons on Code Review are different from other Stack Exchange sites? Is there any specific meaning for it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every graduated Stack Exchange site has their own.

Our story is [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6174/23788) on the design announcement meta - basically the badge icons are part of the customizable things each site gets to pick as their design is being finalized - we settled on curly braces because, well, they're more *code-like* than the originally-suggested design:

[image: badge icons]

Answer (score 4):

They are different in all SE sites.  Image from Academia:

[image]

Comment: Actually I was involved with only Stackoverflow, Ask Different (Apple), Meta StackExchange, Freelancing and this (Code Review). That's why I thought, this is the only different. (Looks like, some of the sites are only different, not all).